# How to add radio buttons dynamically and display them in a button click in map control(windows phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

In my map control there are multiple locations with buttons. So when I click on that particular button in the location two radio buttons should be displayed in the map control.

```
                BasicGeoposition bgp = new BasicGeoposition();

                AppBarButton rd = new AppBarButton();
                bgp.Latitude = loct.lat;
                bgp.Longitude = loct.lng;
                Geopoint hwPoint = new Geopoint(bgp);
                MapControl.SetLocation(rd, hwPoint);
                MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(rd, new Point(0.5, 0.5));

                map1.Children.Add(rd);
```

In this way I added buttons to the map control. In that rd_click how should I implement to display radiobuttons in that location

```
  void rd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
        StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
        st.Children.Add(rb);
        st.Children.Add(rb1);
        // I want to add this stackpanel to the mapcontrol
    }
```

Near to the button the two radio buttons should be displayed in map control. Please help me

The error is shown in the [link](http://1drv.ms/1Gkduzi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to set the location of your StackPanel and then add it as a child of the map like this:

```
MapControl.SetLocation(st, new Geopoint(/* Your location info */));
MyMap.Children.Add(st);
```

Comment: Add the code I provided in your code where you have the comment //I want to add this stackpanel to the mapcontrol.

Comment: I cannot acces the Geopoint. Can you please send me how to pass this geopoint to the rd_click event

Comment: I mean how to pass the GeoPoint parameter to click event

Comment: Here you go:    var loc = MapControl.GetLocation(sender as AppBarButton);

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind reply. I helped me alot